# Performing multiple deletes in Cloud Function

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to perform a delete call to an image the user have uploaded, the user shall also be able to delete their files. So I've made a button in my android code that calls a cloud function:

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("deleteFile1", function(request, response) {

  var fileName = request.params.image1;

  if (!fileName) {
    response.error("Filename is not defined");
  } else {
      Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + fileName,
        headers: {
          'X-Parse-Application-Id': '***',
          'X-Parse-Master-Key': '***'
        },
        success: function(httpResponse) {
          response.success(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
          response.error("Request failed: " + httpResponse.text);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

Now this won't work obviously, I need to delete the object it's related to first. Atleast that's how I have come to understand the deleting process. 
If so, how do I perform first, a deleting of the file's object, then the file itself?

Can I run the object.remove("objectThatHoldsFile"); and do a saveCallBack. When the save have been performed, can I run the cloud function for deleting the file? Or must both parts be handled in the same cloud function in sequence?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Files are ususlly pointed to on parse and the full delete has two steps. 1. Delete the class object, containig the property pointing to the file. 2.in the dashboard settings click the file delete which removes all the files orphaned or no longer holfing pointers

Comment: I want the user to delete their file, not me. I can't go in to every specific user and delete their files when they want to.

Comment: Use rest api  https://www.parse.com/questions/how-can-i-delete-a-file

Comment: @RobertRowntree that's what I'm doing as shown in my question. I was asking how I should or "can" remove the object association with the file since it's mandatory to do so before deleting the file itself, according to some people.

Comment: Delete the object holding the pointer . From that returned promise , do the rest delete on the file.

Comment: @RobertRowntree Could you give an example of that? I'm not sure wether or not I shall delete the object through android code or cloud code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query("myClazz");

  query.get("xWMyZ4YEGZ").then(function(myClazz) {
     _class = myClazz;
     return _class.destroy()
   }
).then(function(fileName) {
      Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + fileName,
        headers: {
          'X-Parse-Application-Id': '***',
          'X-Parse-Master-Key': '***'
        } } ) } )
  .then(function(success) {
    // The related objClazz and file were deleted
  }, function(error) {
    console.error("Error deleting related comments " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
  });
```

Comment: I marked Solved, but just need to have something cleared first, is this method deleting both the object and the file in the same method basically?

Comment: yes and no.... each promise is an independent , asynch, branch on a thread...  each 'then' is append of another chained promise... you could possibly have one of the 2 deletes succeed with the other failing.  look for some docs on 'chaining promises' to clear up... IMO  - a file object on a static CDN  like exists with file objs on parse,  with nothing pointing to it is as good as gone unless someone retreives the file's URL from an image cache and goes after it directly with that URL. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: I see. There's no chance I could, before calling my current cloud function, delete the object from android code with obj.remove("object");  , and on that saveCallback, call the deleteFile cloud method? That would remove that risk that chained promises carry I suppose?